# If $a^{p_1} b^{q_1}\ldots a^{p_n} b^{q_n} = e$ then $S = \{a,b\}$ is not a free generating set of $G = \langle S \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, universal-property

> Let $S = \{a,b\}$ be a generating set for a group $G$. If a non-trivial word in $a, b \in S$ equals the identity $e$ of $G$, i.e.,
> $$a^{p_1} b^{q_1} a^{p_2} b^{q_2} \ldots a^{p_n} b^{q_n} = e$$
> for some $n \in \mathbb N$ and $\{p_j\}_{j=1}^n \subset \mathbb Z$, $\{q_j\}_{j=1}^n \subset \mathbb Z$ where not all $p_i,q_i$ are zero, then, show, using the universal property of free groups, that $S$ is not a free generating set for the group $G$.

---

*Proof Attempt.* For the sake of contradiction, let $S$ be a free generating set of $G$, and denote the inclusion map by $i: S \hookrightarrow G$.

Suppose $\sum_i p_i \ne 0$ or $\sum_i q_i \ne 0$. Consider the map $\phi: S \to \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ given by $\phi(a) = (1,0)$ and $\phi(b) = (0,1)$. By the universal property of free groups, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\widetilde \phi: G \to \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ such that $\phi = \widetilde \phi \circ i$. Then,
$$\widetilde \phi(a^{p_1} b^{q_1} a^{p_2} b^{q_2} \ldots a^{p_n} b^{q_n}) = \widetilde \phi(e) = (0,0)$$
gives $$p_1 \widetilde \phi(a) + q_1\widetilde \phi(b) + p_2\widetilde \phi(a) + q_2 \widetilde \phi(b) + \ldots + p_n \widetilde \phi(a) + q_n \widetilde \phi(b) = (0,0)$$
and $\widetilde \phi(a) = \phi(a), \widetilde \phi(b) = \phi(b)$ simplifies the above expression to $$\left(\sum_i p_i, \sum_i q_i \right) = (0,0)$$
This contradicts the hypothesis that $\sum_i p_i \ne 0$ or $\sum_i q_i \ne 0$. Thus, $S$ is not a free generating set of $G$.

**Question:** How should I proceed when $\sum_i p_i = 0$ *and* $\sum_i q_i = 0$?

*Remark:* The argument above for the case when $\sum_i p_i \ne 0$ or $\sum_i q_i \ne 0$ can be easily extended to work for larger generating sets, i.e., any set $S$ containing $\{a,b\}$. Define the map $\phi: S \to \Bbb Z^3$ by $\phi(a) = (1,0,0)$, $\phi(b) = \phi(0,1,0)$, and $\phi(s) = (0,0,1)$ for any $s \in S \setminus\{a,b\}$. This extends to a unique group homomorphism $\widetilde \phi: G \to \Bbb Z^3$ such that $\phi = \widetilde \phi \circ i$ and a similar argument as above suffices. I'd like the argument for the second case ($\sum_i p_i = 0$ *and* $\sum_i q_i = 0$) to easily extend to larger generating sets $S$ also.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a simpler argument: Let $F$ be the free group on letters $X$ and $Y$. Then, in $F$, $X^{p_1}Y^{q_1} \ldots X^{p_n}Y^{p_n} = e$ is false unless all the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are $0$, so there can be no homomorphism from $G$ to $F$ mapping $a$ to $X$ and $b$ to $Y$ and $G$ cannot be freely generated by $a$ and $b$. (BTW, you need to add the condition that the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are not all $0$ to your "i.e.".)

Comment: Yes, the idea is along the same lines as showing a free group cannot have torsion.

Comment: @RobArthan: It is not true that it is false unless all the $p_i$ and the $q_i$ are zero. For example, you could have the pairs $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, etc. It is *mostly* right, but you have to be a bit more careful.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I had in mind the canonical form. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes. We can assume no pair is $(0,0)$, and any $0$ is omitted and reduced.

Comment: The point is that you need to find a two-generated group where your word is non-trivial. This is what Rob Arthan is doing in his comment (using the standard "realization" of a free group), and is what you are doing when one of $\sum_i p_i$ or $\sum_i q_i$ is non-zero, as this identity then does not hold in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. If $\sum_i p_i = 0$ *and* $\sum_i q_i = 0$ then this identity holds in every abelian group, therefore to proceed you need to consider some *non-abelian* groups.

Comment: @RobArthan Could you fix your comment in light of Arturo's comment, please? I don't yet understand the idea.

Comment: @user1729 I agree, an appropriate non-abelian group should do it. Do you have a suggestion that might work?

Comment: @stoic-santiago The knee-jerk answer is the same as RobArthan's - pick up your favourite text which covers free groups and apply their "constructive" proof of free groups to get a group with the required properties. This is very technical! I think a more subtle way would be to note that your word is a product of commutators, and so use this view to find a soluble or nilpotent group where your word is non-trivial.

Comment: @user1729: the problem as stated says to use the universal property of free groups. What you call "knee-jerk" and "technical" is what I would call following the line of least resistance in a context where the question is being asked of someone who recently been introduced to the notion of free groups (and may not have heard of commutators or nilpotent groups yet).  I have no idea how your "more subtle" way would work out: can you say more, please?

Comment: @stoic-santiago: by far the easiest thing is to use the standard construction of a free group on two generators. If you look at that that will give you the precise conditions on the exponents that neither you nor I got quite right. The unique representatives either have $n = 0$ (giving $e$) or have all exponents non-zero except possibly the first or the last - but please check the details in your text book or course notes.

Comment: @RobArthan In order to use the universal property of free groups, one must first construct a group with the required properties. Constructing the group you use is technical, although standard. Moreover, it would be odd for a question to stipulate that they should use the universal property of free groups but where the expected answer is to use the standard construction.

Comment: (FWIW I've just realised that my idea is actually an old theorem of Magnus (it is equivalent to free groups being residually nilpotent). So, along with my meta-argument for not using the standard construction, I'm really not sure how to proceed. Maybe the OP could give some more context, to see if the standard construction is actually reasonable?)

Comment: @user1729 For context - I'm fairly new to free groups, and the text I am using defines free groups (generated by a given set) using the universal property only. Therefore, I wanted to prove this result using just the universal property - and I believe I am halfway through since only the $\sum_i p_i = \sum_i q_i = 0$ case is left to address. The text does show (later) that the free group $F(S)$ generated by $S$ is unique up to isomorphism, and gives a construction - namely equivalence classes of words on the generating set. I don't know what you mean by the *standard construction.*

Comment: @stoic-santiago: the standard construction is the one you have been taught, using equivalence classes of words on a generating set. You also need a definition of the term "free generating set". When you have that, my original comment should give you the answer.

Comment: @RobArthan We have defined a "free generating set" $S$ as one that satisfies the universal property, and this means we should construct an appropriate non-abelian group $H$ and a morphism $\varphi: S \to H$. By the universal property, this yields $\widetilde \varphi: G \to H$, which we can use on both sides of the given relation to obtain a contradiction (if $H$ and $\varphi$ are chosen appropriately.)

Comment: Have you been taught a construction of a group freely generated by an arbitrary set $S$? If so, that is the group you want to use for $H$. If not, then you are being asked to invent that construction for yourself (which sounds rather a harsh task).